# error: conditional compilation flags must be valid Swift identifiers (rather than '-sdk')

Tags: swift, xcode, sirikit

I'm trying to add the *Intents Extension* to my app (Xcode 10.1) that use Swift 4 and CocoaPods.

After I added the *Intents Extension* and embedded into my target (I have a couple of targets), I tried to build and got the following error:

```
CompileSwiftSources normal x86_64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler
    cd /Users/USER/iOS
    export DEVELOPER_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    export SDKROOT=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator12.1.sdk
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc -incremental -module-name MyApp_Intents -Onone -enable-batch-mode -enforce-exclusivity=checked -DDEBUG -Onone -enable-bridging-pch -DDEBUG -D -sdk
...
<unknown>:0: error: conditional compilation flags must be valid Swift identifiers (rather than '-sdk')
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 1
```

This are my values for *Other Swift Flags*:

```
-Onone -enable-bridging-pch -DDEBUG -D
```

I've looked to [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45876616/error-conditional-compilation-flags-must-be-valid-swift-identifiers-rather-tha) [issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45362162/swift-conditional-compilation-flags-must-be-valid-swift-identifiers), but in my case, the compiler is complaining about a "*-sdk*" value that I cannot found, I even tried to remove some values (and in a moment of despair, all) from *Other Swift Flags*, but unfortunately, when I remove them, a "*Macro name must be an identifier swift*" error appears.

Anyone on this?

Comment: “This are my values for Other Swift Flags:” Well that looks totally illegal.

Comment: O_o’... What do you mean?

Comment: "Other Swift Flags" is an outdated and very tricky setting that requires every entry to be preceded by `-D`. You are not in that format, and your `-D` at the end is throwing everything else off because we end up with `-D -sdk` due to the following `-sdk` put in by the compiler as part of the full command. You should instead abandon Other Swift Flags entirely and Active Compilation Conditions or, where possible, use the scheme editor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Other Swift Flags entry is outmoded and in an incorrect format. Delete it! (Not just its contents; delete the entire build setting.)

Use Active Compilation Conditions instead; it's much easier. This is what a modern project looks like:

[image]

You should not need `-Onone` at all, as optimization level is now a build setting.

[image]

If you want to use the bridging PCH, there is now a build setting for that too.

[image]

Nothing you are doing requires the use of Other Swift Flags, so don't use them.

Comment: Wow... that really change the way I looked to the "Other Swift Flags" and that explain why some values where duplicated on the output.